# Strong convexity implies existence of local optimal

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convex-optimization, optimal-control, stability-theory

I am reading [this thesis (2006)](https://d-nb.info/982143419/34) by Daniel Wachsmuth on the optimal control of the unsteady Navier-Stokes equations. In **Chapter 5: Stability of Optimal controls** of this thesis, he use strong convexity to obtain the existence and uniqueness of the optimal control.

> **Theorem 5.3.** Assume that ($\overline{y}, \overline{u},\overline{\lambda}$) satisfy the first-order necessary optimality condition and the coercivity condition (SSC). Then the perturbed linear-quadratic optimal control problem ($P_z$) admits a unique optimal control $u_z$.

> *Proof.* Let us denote the Lagrangian associated to ($P_z$) by $\mathcal{L}^{(z)}$. Then it holds for all $y, u, \lambda$
> $$\mathcal{L}^{(z)}_{vv}(y,u,\lambda)=\mathcal{L}_{vv}(\overline{y},\overline{u},\overline{\lambda}).$$
> Now take two controls $u_1, u_2 \in \widetilde{U_{ad}}$ with associated solutions $y_1, y_2$ of (5.13b). Then
> the pair $(y_1 − y_2, u_1 − u_2)$ fits in the assumption of (SSC), and we find
> $$\mathcal{L}_{vv}(y,u,\lambda)[(y_1 − y_2, u_1 − u_2)^2]=\mathcal{L}_{vv}(\overline{y},\overline{u},\overline{\lambda})[(y_1 − y_2, u_1 − u_2)^2] \geq \delta \left\| u_1 - u_2\right\|_2^2.$$
> Thus, the problem ($P_z$) is convex on the space of admissible controls $\widetilde{U_{ad}}$. Thus, the problem ($P_z$) as a linear-quadratic optimization problem with strongly convex
> objective functional is uniquely solvable.

The second-order sufficient condition ($SSC$) in the proof is given by
$$\begin{cases}\text{There exist $\varepsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that}\\ \mathcal{L}_{vv}(\overline{y},\overline{u},\overline{\lambda})[(w,h)^2] \geq \delta \left\| h\right\|_2^2\\ \text{for all $h \in \mathcal{T}_{U_{ad}}(\overline{u}), h_i=0$ on $Q_{\varepsilon,i},i=1,2$}\\ \text{and $w$ is the solution of the equation}\\
\begin{cases}w_t+Aw+B'(\overline{y}) = h\\w(0)=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$$

where $\mathcal{T}_{U_{ad}}(\overline{u})$ is the tangent cone of $U_{ad}$ at $\overline{u}$.

I have some questions on Wachsmuth's argument:

(1) Does the pair $(y_1 − y_2, u_1 − u_2)$ satisfies the condition ($SSC$)? It is not clear that whether $u_1-u_2 \in \mathcal{T}_{U_{ad}}(\overline{u})$ or not.

(2) Does strong convexity implies existence of optimal control as in his proof of **Theorem 5.3**?